# Java Sun/Oracle Bug database: new URL?

Tags: java

It seems the Sun URL is finally broken: http://bugs.sun.com/

though it's still mentioned at:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/community/index.html

I could still file a bug at: http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/

But even the link in the mail mentions: http://bugs.sun.com/

Has anybody found the new link?

**UPDATE** Use this link: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/ - bug numbers preserved!

Comment: I believe the right one really is http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/. Someone probably forgot to update the mail.

Comment: ? That's the link I posted where I filed the bug. But I cannot browse the bugs there...

Comment: You didnt say (until the comment) you were trying to browse the bug database. As I said, that URL is the one for reporting. The URL http://search.oracle.com/search/search?search_p_main_operator=all&start=1&group=bugs.sun.com&q=text is the search database function. The whole `bugs.sun.com` is out.

Comment: @acdcjunior hmm, but even there all links direkt to http://bugs.sun.com/ which gets redirected...

Comment: Yes... The site is down, but it seems this is not supposed to be happening. Can you check web.archive.org (I cant from here), maybe they have some date where they could access that URL. The google cache points to 9/mai/2013. So this is very recent.

Comment: Hey! http://bugs.sun.com/ is back on! So it was **not** supposed to be down anyway.

Comment: @acdcjunior great! If you summarize your comments in an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: This question is asking for an _official_ resource, which [is permitted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385479/354577). I'm voting to reopen from the reopen queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time this question was asked, the URL was still http://bugs.sun.com.  However, the bug database site was temporarily down, and pointed to Oracle's main site (as mentioned in the question).  The outage appeared to be unintended behavior.

---

### Additional context during the outage

For filling bug reports, the right URL really is http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/.

To **search/browse the bug database**, you can use the [Oracle Search site function](http://search.oracle.com/search/search?search_p_main_operator=all&start=1&group=bugs.sun.com&q=text). If you try it, you'll see that every answer points to http://bugs.sun.com (such as [this](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8010486)), and when you go there, the page does not open.

If the site really went out, an approach is to check http://web.archive.org and check the last date they got to that URL (if they ever got to it). Google search cache is also a good one. Right now, the google cache of bugs.sun.com points to **May 9, 2013**. So this is very recent.

Comment: Huh, for a while there I thought sun.com was going to make it the whole week without an hours-long outage. :)

Answer (score 1):

The Java Bug Database is currently (as of November 2023) located at https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/.

Any bugs.sun.com URLs redirect to this new location, though they link to this landing page, and not the corresponding issue.  For instance, http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6754672 redirects to https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/, not to https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6754672.

The bug ID have not changed, and can be entered in the "Search by Bug ID" field on the landing page to open a specific bug.